ifstream not getting every file correct
I'm trying to read files in my project for my GLSL shaders using this code to read them that I have revised many times to try and make sure that no data was lost when converting to a char* but it still has this weird issue where it reads out my fragment shader correctly but not my vertex. I also run the function on my vertex shader first and it doesn't read out the vertex shader file correctly but magically works on the fragment shader.
char* vertexShaderSource;
char* fragmentShaderSource;

std::string pathToVertexShader = "./src/shaders/vertexShader.vert";
std::string pathToFragmentShader = "./src/shaders/fragmentShader.frag";

readFileToString(pathToVertexShader, &vertexShaderSource);
readFileToString(pathToFragmentShader, &fragmentShaderSource);

std::cout << vertexShaderSource << std::endl;
std::cout << fragmentShaderSource << std::endl;


The strange thing is that in the console, the value of vertexShaderSource is the last few lines of fragmentShaderSource:
5, 0.2, 1.0); <--- thats it?
}

#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
  FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
}

My readFileToString function is as follows
void readFileToString(std::string pathToFile, char** fileContentCString) {
   std::string fileContent;
   std::ifstream filestream(pathToFile);
   if (!filestream) {
      std::cerr << "Failed to load file: " << pathToFile << std::endl;
      return;
   }

   std::string currentLine;
   while (getline(filestream, currentLine)) {
       fileContent += currentLine + "\n";
   }

   filestream.close();

   *fileContentCString = (char*)fileContent.c_str();
}

I also tried GDB'ing it and for some reason but it just spams these weird characters on the console

I tried deleting and manually typing the file again to no avail so it may be some issue with my function.
This is what I run using g++
g++ -g -I./include -I./src -L./lib src/glad.c src/main.cpp src/window.cpp -lglfw3dll -o donut.exe

People and their C-strings again. Your *fileContentCString assigns a C-string from a std::string, which is a local variable and gets deleted when you exit the function... so you end up with a garbage pointer as result. Make the function return the std::string and don't ever use char* for anything.

You are effectively returning a pointer to a local variable. Return the string object itself,

Thanks for the tips! I need to learn more about pointers and c strings haha

Yes void readFileToString(std::string pathToFile, char** fileContentCString) { probably should have this signature: std::string readFileToString(std::string pathToFile); {

@LanceDyChua -- better to learn about not using pointers and C-style strings. The type of vertexShaderSource should be std::string; you can use vertexShaderSource.c_str() when you need to pass the string contents to whatever needs the C-style string.

Also, nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.
